# Update Entity model from another model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my code I have several lines of code which looks like this:

```
Insertions["sale"] = (modelEntities, entity) => modelEntities.AddToSale((Sale) entity);
```

It works fine when there is no such entity in database. But I want to update entity when it is already in database. It can be done via `Find` method and fields assignment but I want to keep  a pretty code and use something like initialization from constructor or `Insert-or-Update`.

How can I do this?

Comment: First the bigger picture. What is the intention of your line of code? Why the dictionary?

Comment: It is the dictionary with lambdas to add entities to database by type which stored in string. I want to add entity when there is no such entity and update if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think it is useless to build a dictionary with add/insert method delegates. It's a lot of repetitive code. The context has generic methods to insert or update any entity object. You can even make one method that does both, for example (based on `ObjectContext`):

```
public static void Upsert<T>(this ObjectContext context, T entity, int key)
  where T : EntityObject
{
  if (entity != null)
  {
    ObjectSet<T> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    if (key > 0)
    {
      if (entity.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
      {
        objectSet.Attach(entity);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want you can even factor out the `key` argument by getting the key field from the EF model and doing some reflection on the `entity`, but that probably slows down the process remarkably.

Note that an `Attached` persisted object is ignored by this method: it is assumed that it will be saved by the context it already belongs to.